# How to use "readonly = true attribute on @Html.TextBoxFor"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a simple helpdesk application to improve my C# skills

The problem:
I want to pass the current logged in user back to be stored in the database. Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RaisedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10 ">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RaisedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @Value = User.Identity.Name.ToString() })
    </div>
</div>
```

If I use @Html.TextBoxFor I am able to successfully pass my current logged in user to the database. However, when I try to add a readonly = true attribute I get an error.

Code that doesn't work:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RaisedBy, htmlAttributes: new 
{ @Value = User.Identity.Name.ToString(), readonly = true })
```

I've spent a good few hours trying different combinations but I fear it's my inexperience, I'm probably overlooking something really simple. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an error because readonly is a keyword in C#. In order to use keywords as variable names you need to prefix them with an @. Just set @readonly = true